# Two series and corresponding Riemann Sums

Tags: definite-integrals, riemann-integration

Let $$S_{n}=\sum_{r=n}^{3n-1}\frac{n}{r^2-4rn}$$ and $$T_{n}=\sum_{r=n+1}^{3n}\frac{n}{r^2-4rn}$$

**To prove that** $$S_{n}<ln\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$$ and $$T_{n}<ln\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$$

I am having difficulty converting the sums to Riemann Integrals

Comment: To get you started,

$${n\over r^2-4rn}={n/n^2\over(r/n)^2-4rn/n^2}={1\over n}\cdot{1\over\left(r\over n\right)^2-4{r\over n}}$$

Can you take it from there?

Comment: On taking summation and limits both sums convert to integral $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x^2-4x}dx=\ln\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$$. But then why should the sums be less than the value of this integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First observe $S_n = T_n$:
$$\begin{align}
S_n &= \sum_{r=n}^{3n-1} \frac{n}{r (r-4n)}\\
&= \sum_{t={n+1}}^{3n} \frac{n}{(4n-t)(-t)} \\
&= \sum_{r=n+1}^{3n} \frac{n}{r (r-4n)}\\
&= T_n
\end{align}$$
where substitution $t = 4n-r$ was used, then dummy variable changed. So, it suffices to show $\frac{S_n + T_n}{2}< -\frac{1}{2} \ln 3$.

We know
$$\frac{S_n + T_n}{2} = \frac{1}{2n}\left[f(1) + 2\sum_{r=n+1}^{3n-1} f\left({r\over n}\right) + f(3)\right]$$
where $f(x) = {1 \over x^2 - 4x}$, which you can recognise as the trapezium rule. But $f$ is convex, so the approximation is always less than the integral, hence
$$\frac{S_n + T_n}{2} < \int_1^3 \frac{1}{x^2 - 4x} dx=-\frac{1}{2} \ln 3$$
as required.

Comment: Can same idea be applied to $$S_{n}=\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{n}{n^2+rn+r^2}$$ and $$S_{n}=\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\frac{n}{n^2+rn+r^2}$$.Here, $$S_{n}=T_{n}+\frac{1}{2n}$$ and the corresponding integral is $$\frac{\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}$$.How to justify that $$T_{n}<\frac{\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}<S_{n}$$

Comment: If you have another question, you should post it separately.

Comment: Ok. I am posting.

Answer (score 0):

Both sums will give the same integral when you take the limit
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{r=n}^{3n} \frac{n}{r^2-4nr} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{r=n}^{3n} \frac{1}{(r/n)^2-4r/n} \rightarrow \int_{1}^{3} \frac{dx}{x^2-4x}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now partial fractions
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{x(x-4)} =\frac{1}{4}  \left( \frac{1}{x-4} - \frac{1}{x} \right).
\end{eqnarray*}
The integral is 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{1}^{3} \frac{dx}{x^2-4x} =\frac{1}{4} \left[ \ln(x-4) - \ln(x) \right]_1^3 = -\frac{1}{2} \ln3.
\end{eqnarray*}